# Referencing fields from another class

Tags: java, class, field

I looked all over the internet for this and I need help.

I am trying to access fields from another class using a reference I guess...

for example:

```
public class Ball {
    String name;
    int size;

    public Ball(String n, int s) {
        this.name = n;
        this.size = s;
    }
```

Now I want to use size in another class like:

```
public class Game {
    int length;
    int size; // same as from class Ball
```

Is this valid? I basically want only one "size" field that can be accessed through different classes. I know this might be a very basic question but I am new to java

Thanks

Comment: If you want do something like this, it usually means you have some problems with your analysis :). Why you want to do that? Is it necessary? If you really NEED to do this, you should give the `Ball` instance to the `Game` through constructor and create method for getting size in `Game`... But you should be more specific (the problem is probably not in the sharing the parameter, but with you want to doing it)

Comment: Which ball's size do you want to use?

Comment: My actual code has constructors and instances. I still don't get how to reference the field in another class

Comment: @Drake you use `someVariableWhichHoldsAReferenceToABall.size`, replacing `someVariableWhichHoldsAReferenceToABall` by the name of a variable which holds a reference to a ball.

Answer (score 2):

It seems you probably want something like the following

```
public class Ball {

    private int length;
    private int size;

    // getters/setters
}

public class Game {

    private int length;
    private Ball ball;

    public Game() {

    }

    public Game(int length, Ball ball) {
        this.length = length;
        this.ball = ball;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thank you so much I got it! By the way whats the point of the empty constructors. The one where it just has public Game() { and blank? @rick

Comment: If you don't define it, you'd be restricted to only creating a new Game instance with `new Game(int, Ball)`.  In this case you can create a new Game instance using either `new Game()` or `new Game(int, Ball)`.